# Including Website to the Header of Cover Letter

Tags: letters

I am writing a cover letter for my school and I am using this template that I found on the overleaf website.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cover-letter-template-olin/qktfywzczhbd

In the header where it lists my name, address, phone and email, I would like to include my personal website. What is the function that would allow me to include it? Thank you.

```
% Your Information, please revise
\name{FirstName}{LastName}
\address{1 Brookings Dr}{St. Louis, MO 63130}
\phone[mobile]{314-xxx-xxxx}                   
\email{youremail@wustl.edu}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you are using is based on `moderncv` class. So, according to the package documentation (p. 2):

```
\extrainfo{additional information}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: note that this does not produce a clickable link (for me, in Overleaf)

Comment: Try with `\extrainfo{\url{additional information}}` ('hyperref` package is required)